# Using the richness of syntax highlighting produced by asciidoctor

Tags: css, asciidoctor, literate-programming

[Asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/) will process the file `simple.adoc` containing:

```
:source-highlighter: pygments

[source,java]
Foo bar = baz + qux;
```

using [pygments](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb) to produce many syntax categories

[image: syntax-highlighted code]

We can confirm that the HTML produced is indeed quite rich:

```
<div class="content">
<pre class="pygments highlight">
<code data-lang="java"><span class="tok-n">Foo</span> 
<span class="tok-n">bar</span> <span class="tok-o">=</span> 
<span class="tok-n">baz</span> <span class="tok-o">+</span> 
<span class="tok-n">qux</span><span class="tok-o">;</span>
</code></pre>
</div>
```

But the default stylesheet poorly distinguishes between the syntax categories.

How can I customize the output, perhaps by inserting a new CSS stylesheet or by modifying the values in the existing stylesheet?

**Update**
(Thanks LightGuard) If we save the file `simple-docinfo.html`, whose name matches the file we're processing but has the suffix `-docinfo` and the extension `.html`, containing the one line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="basejump.css">
```

and then run `asciidoctor simple.adoc`, we should see `basejump.css` appear in `simple.html`. But no such `basejump.css` appears. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make changes in another stylesheet and load it with a docinfo file.

**UPDATE 2015-02-25**: You need to include the `:docinfo:` attribute either in the file header, or an the commandline with `-a docinfo`

Comment: Thanks.. I see (http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-attributes-and-file-names) that if I write a file simple-docinfo.html containing '<link rel="stylesheet" href="basejump.css">' and then process simple.html using "asciidoctor simple.html" (no command-line options needed), "basejump.css" should appear in the resulting simple.html, but no such "basejump.css" makes it through. Continuing to look...

Comment: Is your adoc file called simple? The first part of -dockinfo needs to be the same as the source filename, then it should pick up the docinfo and add it to the resulting html.

Comment: The question is now updated to put in context the question in the comment.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the use of the attribute to trigger the docinfo inclusion